# Возможно ли сравнить многомерные списки python?

Tags: python, list, compare

```
a = [['zig', 'zag'], ['one', 'two'], ['din', 'don']]
b = [['zig', 'zag'], ['super', 'puper'], ['dalay', 'lama']]

result=list(set(a) - set(b))
print(result)
```

Но так не получается. Мне нужно сравнить элементы только верхнего уровня.
Есть библиотеки, которые умеют работать с одним массивом и искать там уникальные элементы итд. Может есть какая либа и для сравнения многомерных списков?

Comment: *элементы только верхнего уровня* те внутренние списки целиком?

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html):

```
In [58]: import pandas as pd   #  pip install pandas

In [59]: a = [['zig', 'zag'], ['one', 'two'], ['din', 'don']]
    ...: b = [['zig', 'zag'], ['super', 'puper'], ['dalay', 'lama']]

In [60]: A = pd.DataFrame(a)

In [61]: B = pd.DataFrame(b)

In [62]: A
Out[62]:
     0    1
0  zig  zag
1  one  two
2  din  don

In [63]: B
Out[63]:
       0      1
0    zig    zag
1  super  puper
2  dalay   lama

In [64]: res = pd.concat([A, pd.concat([B]*2)]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)

In [65]: res
Out[65]:
       0      1
1    one    two
2    din    don
```

Answer (score 1):

set не работает для вложенных списков, потому что set основан на хэш-таблице и все его элементы должны быть хешируемыми, а значит, как минимум неизменяемыми.

Список является изменяемым, и хеширование для него не определено. А вот кортежи вполне можно хешировать.

Вот этот код будет работать:

```
a = [('zig', 'zag'), ('one', 'two'), ('din', 'don')]
b = [('zig', 'zag'), ('super', 'puper'), ('dalay', 'lama')]

result=list(set(a) - set(b))
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

элементы a, которых нет в b

```
[x for x in a if x not in b] #  [['one', 'two'], ['din', 'don']]
```